# Writing a standalone Corda client that depends on classes defined in a CorDapp

Tags: corda

I am writing a Corda RPC client that depends on state classes defined in a separate CorDapp.

How can I include these classes as dependencies when running the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the CorDapp JAR as a dependency in the project where you are defining the RPC client:

- Create the CorDapp JAR that your client will depend on. You can do this by running `gradlew deployNodes` in a project where a `deployNodes` task is defined and extracting the CorDapp JAR from one of the node's plugins folders
- Copy the JAR to somewhere in the RPC client project (e.g. `./lib/cordapp-name.jar`)
- Reference the JAR as a dependency in your `build.gradle` file, using the syntax `cordapp files('lib/yo.jar')`. Make sure you set the relative path correctly (e.g. if the `build.gradle` file is nested one level down, the above would become `cordapp files('../lib/yo.jar')`)

Currently, CorDapp JAR dependencies added in this way cannot be referenced from `deployNode`. This will be addressed in a future version of Corda.

Comment: Is there any way we can connect to the node and call the flow with corda.jar or other jar files only(not using the code for security reasons)? if there is a way please share some resources for that.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the relevant CorDapp JARs as a dependency to the project containing your RPC Client. First copy your CorDapp JARs to a folder within your RPC client project. Then inside your RPC client's `build.gradle` file (make sure this is the file in the `clients` directory or the root of the RPC client project) , within the `dependencies{}` block, add the following line:

- `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '../cordapp-jars')`

Make sure to replace the directory path with one that points to the folder that you placed the CorDapp JARs. Lastly, within your RPC client, import the necessary Corda states or flows.